# how to use unix command in src in ansible

Tags: ansible

File is opened if I run the following command from shell:

`ls -l /tmp/uname -n ---file1`

I am trying to run it with fetch:

```
- name: COPY file from remote machine to local

  fetch:

    src: /tmp/`uname -n`---mem-swap.out

    dest: /tmp
```

But it gives me the error:

> file not found: /tmp/`uname -n`---mem-swap.out

Is it possible to execute it in   "src"

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to register the `result` and concatenate the `src` string. For example

```
   - commnad: "uname -n"
     register: result
   - fetch:
        src: "/tmp/{{ result.stdout }}---mem-swap.out"
        dest: "/tmp"
```

Comment: it is almost working, but in /tmp   it creates the dir = `hostname`/tmp/`hostname`---mem-swap.out

Comment: Read the [doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fetch_module.html#parameters) and the parameter `flat` in particular.

Comment: src: "/tmp/{{ result.stdout }}---mem-swap.out"    does no work at all, getting the error:  {"changed": false, "file": "/tmp", "msg": "dest is an existing directory, use a trailing slash if you want to fetch src into that directory"}

Comment: I  put in dest:  /tmp/       and it is working.        Thank you very much, Vladimir

Comment: if I do several hosts and get their mem and swap on my control host(DEST), how I can mv them to 1 file on control host, I tried to do cat with:  cat hostname:/tmp/*mem-swap.out >> hostname:/tmp/file    but it does not work, so how I can create 1 file on my local host and include all the info in 1 file, how that cat can be used on local host only ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. A lookup would help if your were running the playbook on a local system, but unfortunately lookups don't run on remotely managed nodes.

As per the other answer, you can run a task first.

But if you are collecting facts first, why not use an Ansible variable?

```
- name: COPY file from remote machine to local
  fetch:
    src: /tmp/{{ ansible_nodename }}---mem-swap.out
    dest: /tmp
```

Comment: Right. FWIW, both Ubuntu and FreeBSD show `uname -n` and `ansible_nodename`  are equivalent. Do you know, by chance, that `uname -n` is the way `ansible_nodename` is collected by the setup module?

Comment: Fair question @Vladmir - had a quick look and the Ansible setup module calls `platform.node()`, which uses `os.uname()`. If uname is somehow missing or unsupported, it defaults to `socket.gethostname()` (which could see some potential drift, though unlikely)